# Fourier transform supremum estimate

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, supremum-and-infimum

Problem:

> Let $f$ be an $N$ times differentiable complex-valued function on
>    $\mathbb{R}$ and $$\int \left| \; f^{n}(x)  \, \right| dx < \infty, \;
>  \; \; \; n = 0, \ldots, N$$ then $\sup\limits_{\xi} \left| \; \hat{f}(\xi)(1+\left| \xi \right|^N)^{-1}  \, \right| < \infty$.

My attempt:

$$\sup_\xi \left| \; (1 + |\xi|^N)^{-1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx}f(x)dx \, \right| \leq \sup_\xi\left(  \left| \; (1+ |\xi|^N)^{-1} \, \right| \cdot  \left| \; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx \, \right| \right) < \infty$$

Is this okay?

Comment: That's ok for the problem as stated. The solution to the problem as stated has nothing to do with the hypotheses given - it's a completely stupid problem. There was a typo somewhere, could be your typo or the person who proposed the problem, but what the question should _really_ ask you to show is $\sup\limits_{\xi} \left| \; \hat{f}(\xi)(1+\left| \xi \right|^N)  \, \right| < \infty$.

Comment: The problem was stated like this in my textbook. I agree that it should rather ask me to show that

$$\sup_\xi |\hat{f}(\xi)(1 + |\xi|^N)| < \infty$$

Do I then have to use Riemann–Lebesgue N times?

Comment: Regarding the right  version of the problem: What is the Fourier tranform of $f'$, in terms of $\hat f$?

Comment: Would you argue as follows:

Since $\mathcal{F}\{f^{(N)}\}(\xi) = (-i\xi)^{N}\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\xi)$ then we have that

$$\| (1 + |\xi|^N)\hat{f} \| \leq \| \hat{f} \| + \| \hat{f}^{N} \| < \infty$$

Comment: Assumnig the norms in your comment are sups then yes.